# Question about the definition of the right limit

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\lim_{x\rightarrow 5^+}f(x)=7$.Then:

a) exists $a>5: \forall x \in [5,a): f(x)>6$

b) exists $a\in [4,7): \forall x \in (5,a]: f(x)>6$

c) exists $a\in[5,7]: \forall x \in [5,a): f(x)<8$

d) exists $a>7: \forall x \in [7,a): f(x)<6$

for the definition of limit: $\forall r>0$ exists $\epsilon >0: 5<x<5+\epsilon$ then $7-r<f(x)<7+r$

so the d) can be false.

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: which conclusion is right?

Comment: Interval $[5,5)$ doesn't exist, let alone $(5,4]$

Comment: @Alex Actually $[5,5)=\emptyset.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the limit definition, inequalities are strict.

Since the limit is for a right-continuous function, it implies that
$$
\exists \delta: 0<x-5< \delta \Leftrightarrow  5<x<5+\delta
$$
If you set $\delta=1$
Since $f$ can approach $7$ both from below and above, so
$$
|f-7| < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow 7 - \varepsilon < f< 7 + \varepsilon 
$$
now set $\varepsilon =1,  6 <f<8$. So a) is correct,.

Comment: No a) is not correct. We don't know anything about $f(5).$